# adding an attachment to a reply places it in original email outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, attachments, reply

In Outlook 2010.
When I recieve an email with attachments and I then click reply. New message window open I go up too insert attachment. The attachment does not appear on the new window of the message I am replying to. It appears as an add attachment on the original message I received?? How do I fix this? This does not happen If I forward a message with attachments or if a make a new message. I did not think it was possible to add attachments to message you received.

Comment: Please add a screen capture of what's happening.

Comment: To argue the closed status... this happened to me and the answer fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I just experienced this issue a few days ago.  I tried adding an attachment to a reply message, but nothing appeared to happen after I selected the file.  When I looked at the original message later, I noticed the file I tried to attach in the reply showed up twice in the attachments list.  At the same time, I was having an issue where I could not move another application window in front of the Outlook mailbox window...I had to minimize the Outlook window to access windows behind it.  When I closed Outlook and restarted it, it functioned like normal again.